# Class com.sunmeat.firebase.ChatMessage is missing a constructor with no arguments

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public ChatMessage(){
    // Don't delete!!!
    // othewice exception will occur: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:
    // Class com.sunmeat.firebase.ChatMessage is missing a constructor with no arguments
}
```

ProGuard minifyEnabled true When it is deleted and the program is not working.